# Change Composer git source for a package

Tags: php, github, composer-php, git-fork

I pull in a package using Composer with this composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "torophp/torophp": "dev-master",
    },
}
```

When I run `composer install` it seems to pull this package from GitHub directly.

I have created a fork of that repo on github with some small changes. Is there a way I can get composer to pull my version on GitHub instead of the original?

Comment: As for your filed issue on Github: There is no issue - I'd close that.

Comment: Check out my answer on Github. Most likely this will fix it for you: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1551#issuecomment-12978227

Comment: Fyi: I edited your question and removed your updates, because the initial question, if composer were able to pull a fork instead of an original Github repo, was answered and the issue you run into is not directly related to that initial question. So it was just confusing. And since the issue is discussed on the Github issue tracker anyway, all the updates to OP should be removed to keep this page on topic and reduce confusion. Hope you fine with it. Cheers

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If this is your `composer.json`

```
"require": {
  "torophp/torophp": "dev-master"
}
```

and you want to change it and use your fork instead, just add your repository into `composer.json` as follows:

```
"repositories": [
   {
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/your-github-username/torophp"
   }
]
```

**Important**: Do not change the `"require"` part, it must continue using `torophp/torophp`!

After adding the `"repositories"` part, run a `composer update` (or `composer.phar update`) and composer will then download your fork (even though it echoes *"installing  torophp/torophp"* during the operation).

---

**Update (18.09.2014):** *As mentioned by @efesaid in the comments:*

> If your package is published on packagist, you need to add
>   `--prefer-source` option to force installation from VCS.

---

**Note**: For those having issues with pulling from the HTTP(S) source (ie you get `[RuntimeException] Failed to clone https://github.com/your-github-username/torophp, could not read packages from it` when trying to update), you can change the `composer.json` to use the git protocol instead. To do so, change the `composer.json` as follows and run `composer update` again.

```
"repositories": [
   {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "git://github.com/your-github-username/torophp.git"
   }
]
```

---

Now go into `vendor/torophp/torophp` and run `git remote -v` for a double check that you use the desired source for the repository.

From there you can commit the changes to your fork and update it from origin (`git pull origin master`).

---

**Update**: To work with **private** repositories at GitHub, you **must** use git protocol and also must have installed SSH keys for a git client.

Composer reference: [Loading a package from a VCS repository](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

Comment: Did that, and get the error I updated my question with. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Also tried to delete my `vendor` and `composer.lock` and run `composer install`. Same error :/

Comment: The actual composer.json is at https://github.com/Svish/myhymnal/blob/master/composer.json

Comment: So re the github issue this actually is the way to do it, just that you currently have to use the `git://` protocol instead (or copy some files to somewhere else, which I don't want to do :p) Either way, marking this as the answer and updating the answer :)

Comment: Updated the answer again. Using VCS is still the preferable way and works. That it isn't working for some is an individual problem with the user's environment. And you should use git protocol only in case the _regular_ way doesn't work. Thought that should be included in the answer.

Comment: I didn't need to change the type though. Just the url protocol. But yes, good to include it!

Comment: Can the URL be my git server ?

Comment: If your package is published on packagist, you need to add `--prefer-source` option to force installation from VCS.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that it stills says it's updating from the other package name (a fork uses the same name I know, but different location). I spent all day the other day trying to get my fork which I guess I already had! Composer should also state the source along with the package name. Especially in this case. So annoying.