# Composer and third party bugs

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php

While developing a Symfony2 project, I often come across bugs in third party bundles. Most of the time the bugs are subtle but hard to find. For example this week alone I have found three bugs where a value was tested using a simple `if ( $value )` construct but required the use of `( $value !== null)` or `( $value !== false )`.

Without having sufficient permissions on the relevant github pages for the projects in question, the best I can do is push a pull request. It usually takes quite some time for the request to be merged. In the mean time, especially when using the master version, other pull requests are merged which in turn leads composer to update. When that happens, any local bug fixes will revert back to the original code.

Is there any method to handle this situation?

Ideally, I would like the third party bundle to update but have my modifications persist. Until the pull request is merged of course.

Comment: Why don't you fork the project?

Comment: @COil Forking will essentially be a different source which I have to sync myself instead of letting composer do it's magic ;)

Comment: See my answer, I don't think that there is any other possibility for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer does not support this functionality out of the box. The reason is simple, one should not work with the development versions of other libraries. But fear not, you can easily work around this by forking the projects on GitHub. Of course this means **a lot** of overhead, but it is the best solution I can think of with which you can tackle this problem.

Note that this approach has several advantages over the patch approach:

1. You can directly create your pull request from your fork.
2. The git merge process will identify any conflicts.

A script to automate this process is easy:

```
#!/bin/sh

git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/master
```

You could create a Composer post update/install script which executes these command in each projects local directory if it is one of your forks. (I leave this implementation part to the reader. But one would need to create the repository locally first, since Composer only downloads the latest files without an repository data. This might add huge `.git` folders to a project since some projects are, well, huge.)

Comment: It's that overhead you mention which I'm trying to avoid. But, it may be the only option. I wonder if github imposes any limits...

Comment: I know but you always will have some overhead. Of course you can automate all the commands which are necessary to perform these actions in a shell script or just another PHP script if you are on Windows. What kind of limits to you mean?

Comment: By limits, I mean number of forks, repository sizes etc. on their free plan. Just reading the docs now and it appears not. To further on your idea, I could create a script to be run by php and add it to the composer pre-update. The only overhead then would be to routinely check on the status of my pull request.

Comment: No limits for public stuff, I updated my answer with more thoughts on the topic. You don't even need a new branch. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to fit exactly what I want, especially with the script feature :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a project that allows you to apply patches after downloading packages with composer. It is created to be used with the Drupal project but I believe it should work with your own patches just as well.

https://github.com/jpstacey/composer-patcher

Otherwise, you could fork the project, make you improvements, submit a pull request and in the mean time use your own forked repository in composer. See [this answer][https://stackoverflow.com/a/14637668/3492835) for a detailed description of how to achieve that.

**Edit:**
The stars say it is about to be 2016 now, and a few things have changed.
`jpstacey/composer-patcher` is considered deprecated in favour of the [netresearch/composer-patches-plugin](https://github.com/netresearch/composer-patches-plugin) project. This is a Composer plugin which does basically the same, but it is able to apply local patches as well.

Comment: While I like your answer, the best I can do is upvote since Fleshgrinder's answer is more in tune with and details what I want to accomplish :)

Comment: No problem, I would go for Fleshgrinder's solution as well :) Just thought it might be an option worth considering. The composer-patcher project has another limitation which is that it can only fetch patches from a remote address.

Comment: Nice sentence. ;) I too upvoted your answer, since it is a valid approach as well.