# Why is composer not using my repository fork for a package?

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I followed information on the internet and this post ([Change Composer git source for a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636936/change-composer-git-source-for-a-package)) but am still having no luck getting composer to use my fork of the repository. What is wrong here?

```
{
"name": "sociablegroup/reeb",
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://github.com/michael-bender/laravel-doctrine.git"
  }
],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
    "beatswitch/lock": "0.1.*",
    "beatswitch/lock-laravel": "0.2.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "~2.0",
    "league/tactician": "0.5.*",
    "doctrine/migrations":"@dev",
    "atrauzzi/laravel-doctrine": "dev-master"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/generators": "~1.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

I've tried using the SSH url instead of HTTPS. I've tried with --prefer-source. I just can't seem to get it to pull in from my repo.

Answer (score 5):

**Issue 1 - Using private Github repo**

Ok, you are trying to "overload" the package `atrauzzi/laravel-doctrine` with your own private package `michael-bender/laravel-doctrine`. 
Your package has a 1.0.0 release, but does not resolve into a stable set of packages.

> The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting

You might add `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to the `config` section of `composer.json`.

Then run `composer update`.

Then you get

```
[217.1MB/57.13s]   - Installing atrauzzi/laravel-doctrine (dev-master 906ccf0)
[217.0MB/57.13s] Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/michael-bender/laravel-doctrine/zipball/906ccf03e9740fb89503427f6bf9c4f019eb33f8
```

---

**Issue 2 - Invalid classmap entry**

There is one more issue:

```
[144.4MB/60.26s] Generating autoload files

  [RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "database" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

In order to get rid of this exception, remove this

```
"classmap": [
    "database"
],
```

from the `autoload` section of `composer.json`.

---

**Reproduce**

I used the following `composer.json` to reproduce and resolve the issue:

```
{
    "name": "sociablegroup/reeb",
    "repositories": [
      {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/michael-bender/laravel-doctrine.git"
      }
    ],
    "require": {
        "atrauzzi/laravel-doctrine": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/migrations": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    }
}
```

I used the following command: `composer install -vvv --profile --prefer-source`.

This fetched your repo - see your last commit:

[image]

Screenshot: `composer.lock`
[image: screeny composer.locl]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought you were able to override the minimum stability requirement on a per package basis by including just the `dev` or `@dev` tag on the package. For example I had to include the @dev on the doctrine/migration package to get it to pull that in correctly which is references via dev commit hash in laravel-doctrine. When I set minimum stability to dev it pulls in dev for everything it seems, even when I do a prefer stable. Any thoughts on how to tell composer to just allow dev on the laravel-doctrine package?

Comment: Yes, i was just lazy and used minimum-stability dev for all packages. You are right: one can set stability per package with `@dev`. You could probably drop `"minimum-stability": "dev"` in favor of `"atrauzi/laravel-doctrine":      "dev-master@dev"` - i still have a feeling that `"dev-master@dev"` is kind of implicitly duplicating, that a "dev" package is requested, but it seems to work. (Sry: what a hell lot of packages. Takes ages to reproduce this issue.)

Comment: Tried `"dev-master@dev"` and just `@dev` for `"atrauzi/laravel-doctrine"` but neither seem to be working as I don't see the changes I've made in my private repo on the master branch.

Comment: Did you use `--prefer-source`?

Comment: I tried with --prefer-source and no luck. Composer.lock still reporting the atrauzzi repo. I think I've tried everything. Even when I set minimum stability to dev for everything it still does not read my fork. I'm close to filing an issue with composer. Have you been able to get it to pull my fork over the atrauzi one? Do you have latest version of composer?

Comment: Yes, i'm using the latest version of Composer. I've tested this with minimum-stability: dev and it pulls and uses your repo instead of the atrauzi one. This works for me. That's why i posted the output of Composer, see above and here: `Installing atrauzi/laravel-doctrine & Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/michael-bender/laravel-doctrine/zipball/906ccf03e9740fb89503427f6bf9c4f019eb33f8`

Comment: Checked the githash, too! It points to your repo: https://github.com/michael-bender/laravel-doctrine/commit/906ccf03e9740fb89503427f6bf9c4f019eb33f8

Comment: Updated my answer with a reduced `composer.json`. Removed all the packages, the are implicitly added by the other dependencies. That allows to focus on the real problem. But it was also solved before.. Just take a look. The repo fetched is yours. Don't let the folder name fool you, your code lives in **atrauzi/laravel-doctrine**. Just like the composer.json of your package defines.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort. I tried this as well and it looked like it was actually pulling in my repo. However the code was not what was checked in at master in my repo (still had the Trait directory instead of a Util directory). Do you know if composer.lock should reference my repo as the "url"? It does not if it should. I got my required change merged into the upstream branch so my urgency to resolve this is less. However, I still want to get it working.

Comment: Ok, glad i could help. We are talking about the master branch with latest commit "906ccf03". If you want another branch, maybe "feature/trait_move", then you need to specify that. Yes, the `composer.lock` should contain the URL for your github repo as `source.url` for the `atrauzi/laravel`package. And it does this.. :)

Comment: I think the issue was I had `"type":"vcs"`. I saw you had `"type:"git"`. I tried with `"type":"git"` and it worked. I had everything right from the beginning it would seem other than the type. If you'd like make a new post to identify that as the issue I'm happy to mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Glad you figured it out !! (It's a bit strange that the `type git` makes the difference, because with `type vcs` Composer will try several adapters (svn,hg,git) to detect the correct one. I used this only to skip the automatic guessing and use the specifc type git to be faster during reproduction of the issue. If this really makes the difference, then i consider it a Composer issue.)

Comment: It appears this code doesn't work with the latest version of Composer. I'm on `1.0-dev (417516098edb9b3c9d433c9b6527b0f1492362f4)`. Whenever I run this, I still get messages about `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` (I tried it with the same `composer.json` file mentioned above). I also cleared the composer caches and tried it with a different repository.

Comment: Ah, the composer package name is incorrect in the example above - should be `atrauzzi/laravel-doctrine` (with two z's instead of one).

Comment: For anyone stumbling on this page years later - You shouldn't be setting the min stability to dev.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar problem, attempting to pull my fork of a repository using composer. In addition to setting "minimum-stability" to "dev" and adding your repository URL to the "repositories" section, you may also have to edit the "name" field of your package's composer.json to match the URL of the package on GihHub.

For example this would be the "name" field in your package's composer.json on GitHub:

```
{
  "name": "michael-bender/laravel-doctrine"
  ...
}
```

Comment: I had this same issue, but I was trying to require a branch other than the master branch. The branch I was including had the same name as the package, but the master branch had a different name. It looks like composer checks the master branch for the name and moves on if it's different. I updated the master branch to have the same name as the package and then composer was able to include my other branch without an issue.